# HTML to PDF conversion with external CSS support in Codeigniter

Tags: css, codeigniter, pdf, mpdf

After comparing the features in dompdf, TCPDF, MPDF, I am using MPDF here to convert HTML to PDF in my codeigniter application. In localhost, its working properly. And pdf is generated within 2 or 3 seconds. When i upload it in live server, it takes more than 3 minutes to create the same pdf file. I have checked with file permissions. Pdf is generating and saved in folder. But it takes large time.

```
$this->ci->load->library('m_pdf');
$html = $this->ci->load->view('ecommerce/salespdf',$this->data,true);
$m_pdf = $this->ci->m_pdf->load();
$m_pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$filepath = getcwd()."/assets/other_uploads/pdf_files/";
$m_pdf->Output($filepath.$filename, "F");
```

From the above code, pdf is generating in the specified folder, but takes long time. Only one external css file is included in the view file.

```
<link href="<?php echo CSS_URL; ?>pdf-invoice.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Is anything wrong in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i fixed the bug. The problem is loading image inside the view page. Here i am adding header with Company name and logo.

```
http://domain.com/assets/other_uploads/photo/photo.png
```

If i give the above source in image URL, it tries to load the image in my view page and it fails. So, i used the below code to fix this.

```
var/www/domain/assets/other_uploads/photo/photo.png
```

For external css issue, i added the css part in view page as internal css.

It works now!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
function WriteHTML($html,$bi)
    {
        //remove all unsupported tags
        $this->bi=$bi;
        if ($bi)
            $html=strip_tags($html,"<a><img><p><br><font><tr><blockquote><h1><h2><h3><h4><pre><red><blue><ul><li><hr><b><i><u><strong><em>"); 
        else
            $html=strip_tags($html,"<a><img><p><br><font><tr><blockquote><h1><h2><h3><h4><pre><red><blue><ul><li><hr>"); 
        $html=str_replace("\n",' ',$html); //replace carriage returns with spaces
        // debug
        if ($this->debug) { echo $html; exit; }

        $html = str_replace('&trade;','™',$html);
        $html = str_replace('&copy;','©',$html);
        $html = str_replace('&euro;','€',$html);

        $a=preg_split('/<(.*)>/U',$html,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
        $skip=false;
        foreach($a as $i=>$e)
        {
            if (!$skip) {
                if($this->HREF)
                    $e=str_replace("\n","",str_replace("\r","",$e));
                if($i%2==0)
                {
                    // new line
                    if($this->PRE)
                        $e=str_replace("\r","\n",$e);
                    else
                        $e=str_replace("\r","",$e);
                    //Text
                    if($this->HREF) {
                        $this->PutLink($this->HREF,$e);
                        $skip=true;
                    } else 
                        $this->Write(5,stripslashes(txtentities($e)));
                } else {
                    //Tag
                    if (substr(trim($e),0,1)=='/')
                        $this->CloseTag(strtoupper(substr($e,strpos($e,'/'))));
                    else {
                        //Extract attributes
                        $a2=explode(' ',$e);
                        $tag=strtoupper(array_shift($a2));
                        $attr=array();
                        foreach($a2 as $v) {
                            if(preg_match('/([^=]*)=["\']?([^"\']*)/',$v,$a3))
                                $attr[strtoupper($a3[1])]=$a3[2];
                        }
                        $this->OpenTag($tag,$attr);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $this->HREF='';
                $skip=false;
            }
        }
    }
```